# Extending native HTML Elements with Polymer

Tags: html, dom, polymer, web-component

Hi i'd like to extend from a native HTML Element with Polymer for creating a custom web component.
My polymer ready-callback is getting called, when i'm not extending. As soon as i extend, nothing gets called anymore. Though the shadow DOM for the element is being created...

Here is my code for the usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Custom Component Usage</title>
        <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="elements/extended-item.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <extended-item>I was extended from div!</extended-item>
    </body>
</html>
```

Custom Element, which extends **div**:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="extended-item" extends="div">

    <template>

        <content></content>

    </template>

</polymer-element>

<script>
Polymer('extended-item',
        {
            created: function ()
            {
                console.log('EXTENDED ITEM IS CREATED!');
            },
            ready: function ()
            {
                console.log('EXTENDED ITEM IS READY!');
            },
            attached: function ()
            {
                console.log('EXTENDED ITEM IS ATTACHED!');
            },
            domReady: function ()
            {
                console.log('EXTENDED ITEMS DOM IS READY!');
            },
            detached: function ()
            {
                console.log('EXTENDED ITEM IS DETACHED!');
            },
            attributeChanged: function (attrName, oldVal, newVal)
            {
                //var newVal = this.getAttribute(attrName);
                console.log(attrName, 'old: ' + oldVal, 'new:', newVal);
            }
        });
</script>
```

Any idea?

thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works properly if, instead of referring to the element as `<extended-item>`, you instead use `<div is="extended-item">`.

Here's an example ([jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nagif/6/edit)):

```
<polymer-element name="extended-item" extends="div">
  <template>
    <p>This is part of the template.</p>
    <content></content>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer('extended-item', {
      created: function() {
        console.log('EXTENDED ITEM IS CREATED!');
      },
      ready: function() {
        console.log('EXTENDED ITEM IS READY!');
      },
      attached: function() {
        console.log('EXTENDED ITEM IS ATTACHED!');
      },
      domReady: function() {
        console.log('EXTENDED ITEMS DOM IS READY!');
      },
      detached: function() {
        console.log('EXTENDED ITEM IS DETACHED!');
      },
      attributeChanged: function (attrName, oldVal, newVal)
      {
        //var newVal = this.getAttribute(attrName);
        console.log(attrName, 'old: ' + oldVal, 'new:', newVal);
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<div is="extended-item">I was extended from div!</div>
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out in this comments, this is expected behavior, documented in the [Custom Elements spec](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#dfn-type-extension).

Comment: Whenever you extend a native HTMLElement (other than HTMLElement itself) you must use _type-extension_ syntax `<tag is="custom-name">`. This is part of the [Custom Elements spec](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#dfn-type-extension).

Comment: thanks! i think thats it. :)

I could have seen it under Point 5.4 here: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/components-intro/