# How to select extended custom elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, custom-element

I created a custom element following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636496/extending-native-html-elements-with-polymer) and now `extended-item` doesn't work anymore as a css selector though.

Before:

```
<style>
    extended-item {...}
</style>
<extend-item></extended-item>
```

After:

```
<style>
    ??? {...}
</style>
<div is="extended-item"></div>
```

I tried `div:extended-item` but it doesn't work. Any idea?

**[EDIT]**

Here is my example `extended-item`

```
<link rel="import" href="../libs/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="extended-item" noscript extends="div">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host { ... }
        </style>
        ...
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Note that using `noscript` and `extends` together won't allow me to use `<extended-item>` syntax directly, but only the other `<div is="extended-item">` syntax which doesn't seem to work with selectors. Registering the element this way is equivalent but will let me use both syntax, thus allowing the selector to work:

```
<link rel="import" href="../libs/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="extended-item">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host { ... }
        </style>
        ...
    </template>
    <script>
        (function(){ Polymer('extended-item', {extends: 'div'}); })()
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be better as a comment than an answer, but I can't comment yet. You say `extended-item` doesn't work as a css selector - did you try the attribute selector `[attr=value]` ? In your case perhaps `div[is="extended-item"] { /*styling*/ }`

Comment: it doesn't seem to work as of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFontana/fkc8wbub/)

Comment: Sloppy on my part, sorry. Thank you ebidel!