# Faking jQuery :checked selector for a custom Polymer element

Tags: jquery, dart, polymer

I have a Polymer element which acts as a customized/stylized checkbox.

It's essentially a section which wraps a checkbox:

```
# Light DOM
<my-checkbox>

  # Shadow DOM/Polymer HTML
  <section id="root">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"/>
  </section>

</my-checkbox>
```

The actual input/checkbox toggles when you click the light DOM element.  I can easily toggle the "checked" attribute/property on `my-checkbox` by listening to "change" of the checkbox.

```
$(@$.checkbox).change () =>

  checked = $(@$.checkbox).is(":checked")

  # Fake the prop "checked" for aci-checkbox
  $(@).prop "checked", checked

  if checked
    $(@).attr "checked", ""
  else
    $(@).removeAttr "checked"
```

What I cannot do is make `my-checkbox` respond to `.is(":checked")`.  [The jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) says that the `:checked` selector wors for checkboxes, radio buttons, and select elements.

**Is there any way to fake this so `my-checkbox` responds to `.is(":checked")`?**

Thanks,

Erik

Comment: Have you tried extending checkbox? Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636496/extending-native-html-elements-with-polymer) of extending native elements.